# External Interrupts failing to be called

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, osdev, gdt

I'm creating a hobby x86_32 bit kernel using C, and simulating it with qemu-system.

After creating a VGA driver, I implemented a GDT successfully (or did I?), after setting up internal and external interrupts, the table is not being called by the kernel, while running a very basic keyboard driver.

The Keyboard.c passes the keyboard interrupt vector(IRQ1) and the keyboard callback function(that is supposed to print the letter). however after passing these two arguments and **Initiating** the keyboard, any key pressed(external interrupt) doesn't call the callback function and nothing happens.

IDT.c --

```
#define low_16(address)(uint16_t)((address) & 0xFFFF)
#define high_16(address)(uint16_t)(((address)>>16) & 0xFFFF)

idt_gate_t idt[256];

idt_register_t idt_reg;


void set_idt_gate(int n, uint32_t handler){
  idt[n].low_offset = low_16(handler);
  idt[n].selector = 0x08;
  idt[n].alwayszero = 0;
  idt[n].flags = 0x8E;
  idt[n].high_offset = high_16(handler);
}

void load_idt(){
  idt_reg.base = (uint32_t) &idt;
  idt_reg.limit = 256 * sizeof(idt_gate_t) - 1;

  asm volatile("lidt (%0)" : : "r"(&idt_reg));
  print_string("IDT loaded..\n");

  asm volatile("sti");   //added after suggestions from this post
}
```

isr.c --

```
isr_t interrupt_handlers[256];

void isr_install(){
    set_idt_gate(0, (uint32_t) isr0);
    set_idt_gate(1, (uint32_t) isr1);
    set_idt_gate(2, (uint32_t) isr2);
    set_idt_gate(3, (uint32_t) isr3);
    set_idt_gate(4, (uint32_t) isr4);
    set_idt_gate(5, (uint32_t) isr5);
    set_idt_gate(6, (uint32_t) isr6);
    set_idt_gate(7, (uint32_t) isr7);
    set_idt_gate(8, (uint32_t) isr8);
    set_idt_gate(9, (uint32_t) isr9);
    set_idt_gate(10, (uint32_t) isr10);
    set_idt_gate(11, (uint32_t) isr11);
    set_idt_gate(12, (uint32_t) isr12);
    set_idt_gate(13, (uint32_t) isr13);
    set_idt_gate(14, (uint32_t) isr14);
    set_idt_gate(15, (uint32_t) isr15);
    set_idt_gate(16, (uint32_t) isr16);
    set_idt_gate(17, (uint32_t) isr17);
    set_idt_gate(18, (uint32_t) isr18);
    set_idt_gate(19, (uint32_t) isr19);
    set_idt_gate(20, (uint32_t) isr20);
    set_idt_gate(21, (uint32_t) isr21);
    set_idt_gate(22, (uint32_t) isr22);
    set_idt_gate(23, (uint32_t) isr23);
    set_idt_gate(24, (uint32_t) isr24);
    set_idt_gate(25, (uint32_t) isr25);
    set_idt_gate(26, (uint32_t) isr26);
    set_idt_gate(27, (uint32_t) isr27);
    set_idt_gate(28, (uint32_t) isr28);
    set_idt_gate(29, (uint32_t) isr29);
    set_idt_gate(30, (uint32_t) isr30);
    set_idt_gate(31, (uint32_t) isr31); 
    print_string("in isr_install\n");
    repro_pic();
    irq_install();
    load_idt();   //added after the suggestions from this post

}

void irq_install(){
    set_idt_gate(32, (uint32_t)irq0);
    set_idt_gate(33, (uint32_t)irq1);
    set_idt_gate(34, (uint32_t)irq2);
    set_idt_gate(35, (uint32_t)irq3);
    set_idt_gate(36, (uint32_t)irq4);
    set_idt_gate(37, (uint32_t)irq5);
    set_idt_gate(38, (uint32_t)irq6);
    set_idt_gate(39, (uint32_t)irq7);
    set_idt_gate(40, (uint32_t)irq8);
    set_idt_gate(41, (uint32_t)irq9);
    set_idt_gate(42, (uint32_t)irq10);
    set_idt_gate(43, (uint32_t)irq11);
    set_idt_gate(44, (uint32_t)irq12);
    set_idt_gate(45, (uint32_t)irq13);
    set_idt_gate(46, (uint32_t)irq14);
    set_idt_gate(47, (uint32_t)irq15);
    print_string("in irq_install\n");
}

void repro_pic(){
  
    // ICW1
    port_byte_out(0x20, 0x11);
    port_byte_out(0xA0, 0x11);

    // ICW2
    port_byte_out(0x21, 0x20);
    port_byte_out(0xA1, 0x28);

    // ICW3
    port_byte_out(0x21, 0x04);
    port_byte_out(0xA1, 0x02);

    // ICW4
    port_byte_out(0x21, 0x01);
    port_byte_out(0xA1, 0x01);

    // OCW1
    port_byte_out(0x21, 0x0);
    port_byte_out(0xA1, 0x0);
    print_string("in repro_pic\n");
  
}



char *exception_messages[] = {
        "Division By Zero",
        "Debug",
        "Non Maskable Interrupt",
        "Breakpoint",
        "Into Detected Overflow",
        "Out of Bounds",
        "Invalid Opcode",
        "No Coprocessor",

        "Double Fault",
        "Coprocessor Segment Overrun",
        "Bad TSS",
        "Segment Not Present",
        "Stack Fault",
        "General Protection Fault",
        "Page Fault",
        "Unknown Interrupt",

        "Coprocessor Fault",
        "Alignment Check",
        "Machine Check",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",

        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved",
        "Reserved"
};

void register_interrupt_handler(uint8_t n ,isr_t handler){
  interrupt_handlers[n] = handler;
  print_string("in register interrupt handler\n");
}

void isr_handler(registers_t *r){
  print_string(exception_messages[5]);
  print_string(exception_messages[(*r).int_no]);
}

void irq_handler(registers_t *r){
  if(interrupt_handlers[r->int_no] != 0){
    isr_t handler = interrupt_handlers[r->int_no];
    handler(r);
  }
  port_byte_out(0x20, 0x20);
  if(r->int_no >= 40){
    port_byte_out(0xA0,0x20);
  }
}
```

keyboard.c --

```
void print_letter(uint8_t scancode){
  switch (scancode) {
    case 0x00:
      print_string("error");
      break;
    case 0x01:
      print_string("esc");
      break;
    case 0x02:
      print_string("1");
      break;
    case 0x03:
      print_string("2");
      break;

    default:
      if(scancode <= 0x7f){
        print_string("unknown key\n");
      }else if(scancode <= 0x39 +0x80 ){
        print_string("key up\n");
        print_letter(scancode-0x80);
      }else{
        print_string("unknown key");
      }
    break; 
  }
}
static void keyboard_callback(registers_t *regs){
  print_string("inkeyboardcallback\n");  
  port_byte_out(0x60, 0x3);
  //uint8_t scancode = port_byte_in(0x60);
  //print_letter(scancode);
}

void init_keyboard(){
  print_string("in init keyboard\n");
  register_interrupt_handler(IRQ1, keyboard_callback);
  uint8_t scancode = port_byte_in(0x60);
  print_letter(scancode);
}
```

**The entire code repository: https://github.com/MadhavBh/FilterCoffee**

about my skepticism regarding the GDT--

I am not familiar with how QEMU logs work, however, after running  `-d int` the IDT and GDT fields in the log are very weird, however at the end of the logs, they are empty. Is it supposed to be like that?

Qemu log--

```
EAX=00000000 EBX=00000000 ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=0000000b EDI=02000000 EBP=000a0000 ESP=00006c5c
EIP=000eeb76 EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=ffffffff CCO=CLR
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=00000000 EBX=00000000 ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=0000000b EDI=02000000 EBP=000a0000 ESP=00006c5c
EIP=000eeb76 EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000044 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=00006cff
ESI=00006cc4 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006c84 ESP=00006c84
EIP=00008a63 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 008f9300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 008f9b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
GS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00006c84 CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=00006cff
ESI=00006cc4 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006c84 ESP=00006c84
EIP=000f8a66 EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000044 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=06feafc0
ESI=000ec440 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006c84 ESP=00006c84
EIP=000f8a7d EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000008 CCD=00006c70 CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=06feafc0
ESI=000ec440 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006c84 ESP=00006c84
EIP=00008a80 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=000069ae EDI=06fff5ce EBP=0000696e ESP=0000696e
EIP=00008a63 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 008f9300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 008f9b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
GS =c900 000c9000 ffffffff 008f9300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000696e CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=000069ae EDI=06fff5ce EBP=0000696e ESP=0000696e
EIP=000f8a66 EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000044 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=0000696e ESP=0000696e
EIP=000f8a7d EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000005 CCD=00000000 CCO=CLR
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=0000696e ESP=0000696e
EIP=00008a80 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =c900 000c9000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=000069a8 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006968 ESP=00006968
EIP=00008a63 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =c900 000c9000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00006968 CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=000069a8 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006968 ESP=00006968
EIP=000f8a66 EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000044 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=06fd3450 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006968 ESP=00006968
EIP=000f8a7d EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000008 CCD=00006954 CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=06fd3450 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006968 ESP=00006968
EIP=00008a80 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =c900 000c9000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=000069ae EDI=06fff5ce EBP=0000696e ESP=0000696e
EIP=00008a63 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =c900 000c9000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=0000696e CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=000069ae EDI=06fff5ce EBP=0000696e ESP=0000696e
EIP=000f8a66 EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000044 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=0000696e ESP=0000696e
EIP=000f8a7d EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000005 CCD=00000000 CCO=CLR
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=00000000 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=0000696e ESP=0000696e
EIP=00008a80 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =c900 000c9000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=000069a8 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006968 ESP=00006968
EIP=00008a63 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =c900 000c9000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00006968 CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f8a66 ECX=00001234 EDX=000069ff
ESI=000069a8 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006968 ESP=00006968
EIP=000f8a66 EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000044 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=06f33450 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006968 ESP=00006968
EIP=000f8a7d EFL=00000012 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f7460 00000037
IDT=     000f749e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000008 CCD=00006954 CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00008a80 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000003
ESI=06f33450 EDI=06fff5ce EBP=00006968 ESP=00006968
EIP=00008a80 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =dd00 000dd000 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =c900 000c9000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
```

Comment: The QEMU output seems to be early on during SMM interrupts so isn't really associated with your code running. You don't seem to call `load_idt` so your IDT is never used; you do an `sti` before interrupts are fully set up in the kernel code; and  in the assembly code you do a `cli` after you return from the kernel and enter an infinite loop (at that point you won't receive further interrupts with interrupts off).

Comment: @MichaelPetch ooff, those are some very embarrassing oversights. Thanks for pointing them out. I used the CLI instruction to disable interrupts for implementing the GDT, however, placing the CLI and STI instructions before and after the critical section doesn't help either. do you see anything else that can go wrong? 

I will edit the changes that I tried after your suggestion in the main post.

Comment: Look at `kerne_main` after you set everything up and enable interrupts you return from `kernel_main` and back to the code in boottwo.asm where the next instruction is `CLI` which turns off interrupts and then you put the processor in an infinite loop.  You effectively tell the CPU to not receive interrupts forever.  You can either create an infinite loop in `kernel_main` that issues a `hlt` instruction or you can remove `cli` from boottwo.asm after calling `kernel_main`. and allow the infinite loop to run with interrupts on.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you so much for your help! you were right, I did disable the interrupts in the boottwo.asm. the kernel is now recognizing the interrupts and calling the handler. However, after an external interrupt, it results in an infinite loop, and calls the keyboard handler infinitely.

Comment: Why are you writing the value 3 to port 0x60 each time a keyboard interrupt is received? (I think that is part of the problem). I'd also recommend putting a `hlt` inside your `.loop` infinite loop. `hlt` instruction actually means 'wait for next interrupt'

Comment: One last note. While not the source of your problems, there is a problem with where you placed the STI. After you set up an IDT with no interrupt handlers in it, any interrupt that comes in that isn't properly handled will end up causing a triple fault/reboot. You should do the STI after you initialize the IDT with proper interrupt (and exception) handlers. As your code is, if you get unlucky enough to get an interrupt after your load the IDT and before you initialize it with handlers it will reboot. You may only see this rarely as the timing of an interrupt has to be right

Comment: @MichaelPetch that was actually just for debugging, I wanted to check if the port functions worked. but YES that fixed it. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Got it Got it. thank you so much! that makes a lot of sense. I'll keep that mind.